# The amount of data that was returned by a data connection has exceeded the maximum limit that was configured by the server administrator

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have infopath form with SharePoint designer approval workflow.
I am showing some details on that form. but when I have more data in SharePoint List it is giving bellow error

```
"The amount of data that was returned by a data connection has exceeded the maximum limit that was configured by the server administrator"
```

I guess Infopath form is getting all the data from the list instead of particular row. can any one please suggest me to filter on current item ?

Answer (score 1):

Resolution: Ensure to follow the below steps.
i.    Open the central administration
ii.    Go to General Application Settings
iii.    InfoPath Form Services
iv.    Configure InfoPath Form Services
v.    Click on Data Connection Response Size
vi.    By default it is 1500 kilobytes
vii.    Change the Response Size in kilobytes (Increase the number).

Comment: That will solve the problem but still infopath will get All data. we can filter that data using rules in infopath so only filtered data will be loaded from the list and it will be less then 1500  kilobytes so no need to configure this !

Comment: Hi mahesh, we can put conditions for  filtering the data  in info paths, so that you can reduce the data size..

Answer (score 1):

In this case what can be happening is that the amount of data you’re pulling back in your queries has grown to an unmanageable size. 
Another possibility is that you’re including additional columns that perhaps you don’t actually need to include – by removing the unnecessary fields this could immediately resolve your issue if you don’t require all the columns.

**For office 365 this one going to work.**
including additional columns that perhaps you don’t actually need to include – by removing the unnecessary fields this could immediately resolve your issue if you don’t require all the columns.