# SharePoint Online InfoPath: Amount of Data that was Returned by Connection has Exceeded the Maximum Limit

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, infopath-forms-services

In SharePoint Online, an InfoPath form is displaying this error:

"The amount of data that was returned by connection has exceeded the maximum limit that was configured by server administrator."

It is easy to increase the maximum limit in SharePoint On-premise, as explained here:

[The amount of data that was returned by a data connection has exceeded the maximum limit that was configured by the server administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790083/the-amount-of-data-that-was-returned-by-a-data-connection-has-exceeded-the-maxim)

However, I am working in SharePoint Online, and there is no option to do this. I cannot find any PowerShell cmdlets, either.

Does anyone know if it is simply impossible to increase the maximum limit (Data Connection Response Size)? If so, what can I do in my form to stop this from happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the default setting and it can not be changed in SharePoint Online.

Please refer below links which clearly indicates that we can not increase the Maximum limit (Data Connection Response Size) in SharePoint Online:

- https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/428229
- https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/252391

You can filter your data and you can pick only those fields which are required. This will reduce the size of data.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In this case what can be happening is that the amount of data you’re pulling back in your queries has grown to an unmanageable size. 
Another possibility is that you’re including additional columns that perhaps you don’t actually need to include – by removing the unnecessary fields this could immediately resolve your issue if you don’t require all the columns.

**For office 365 this one is going to work.**
including additional columns that perhaps you don’t actually need to include – by removing the unnecessary fields this could immediately resolve your issue in Office 365 if you don’t require all the columns.